# ServiceStack Metadata page with restricted services

Tags: metadata, servicestack

I was wondering if there is a way to show on the metadata page only with services by roles, for example if the user has role "operator" : in the metadata servicestack page only can see and access the services B, C and if the user enters with admin role can view and access in the metadata page the services A,B,C,D for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The metadata pages currently supports restricting the visibility and access of services based on the [Request Attribute Restrictions](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Restricting-Services) but there's no support for Role-level or premission-level visibility.

Add it as a [feature request](http://servicestack.uservoice.com/forums/176786-feature-requests) if you would like to see future support for this.